# Ionic command not working

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to run:

ionic build android

Recieving error:
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper

After navigating to  /usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/
See that folder templates not exists there.

Tried to update SDK,it won't help.

Comment: have you installed (from SDK Manager) `Android SDK Tools` , `Android SDK Platform-Tools` & `Android SDK Build-Tools`?

Comment: Yep, All Tools installed. I use openjdk and not oracleJDK , can it be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out(I'm Ubuntu user)

Installed androidSDK to different folder(not folder used by Android Studio) following this guide.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidSDK

Run:  ionic state reset (It deleted android platform) 
Run: ionic platform add android 
Run: ionic build android